# Clues to using Hibernate for generating (bulk) SQL queries without session/connecting to DB

Tags: mysql, hibernate, bulkinsert

I have a specific situation for which I wanted to know how does hibernate use its schema metadata to generate the HQLs or if needed SQLs.

So I have a situation in which object graphs needs to be updated to DB, the deal is that only the fields with not null (or non default) values needs to be updated. Here is my use case: We have a bulk edit functionality which allows our back end support team to be able to update around 25-30 fields for a particular product. So they provide product id and the value against the column needs to be updated.

However using hibernate in this case has its tax, we pull the entire big object graph from DB and then updated the specific field and do a Session.merge. As no. of edits are increasing, this is increasing CPU utilization and now we have to redesign it for 5 times bigger load.

So we want to move to generating sql queries and later run batch updates (even if it means running them directly in SQL). However I was wondering, hibernate already uses metadata smartly to generate queries. If I could only use an interceptor of some sort which would only allow the fields which have non-null values to be included for query generation.

So here is the big, vague question: How does hibernate generate queries. Is there a good place to begin or someone know if something like this has been attempted before.

This problem may look like bulk upload of CSV to MySQL but it is not. Bulk upload/edit is mainly about editing records of same table, in this case the fields belong to 10 different tables so relevant joins need to be inferred. I am only trying to use hibernate to avoid dirty IF-ELSE stmt's for generating SQL code.

Comment: Have you measured that what's taking time is the execution of the update queries? Hibernate only updates entities which have changed. You can tell it to only update the columns that have changed (using Entity.dynamicUpdate), but the Hibernate documentation says that it's often counter-productive (see http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapping-declaration-class)

Comment: No well its not as much about taking time as much about meeting a SLA. So the new design should be able to complete updates within 2 hrs which current strategy is not about to achieve hence need to generate queries. Thanks for the tip, I am exploring that, however it's dirtying my entity classes, so this option needs to be enabled only for bulk edit. In other cases dynamicUpdate should indeed be false. But prob I can draw some clue from this.

Comment: My point is that if the current time is 5 hours and you want to reduce it to 2 hours, you should not optimize the generation of update queries unless you **know** that this is the part which consumes most of the 5 hours time. If it only takes 5 minutes out of the 5 hours and you optimize it by a 500% factor, you will only gain 4 minutes. Measure before optimizing.

Comment: To add to it, this solution too perhaps demands that I have to pull the object from DB or already have the object in session. However I want to avoid pulling from DB to save that time, just generate SQL for  fields which are not null. So it would only utilize a part of hibernate (which if made aware of what fields to include in SQL gen. uses db metadata to generate queries). I am interested in that portion.

Comment: I guess we posted around same time. I had done some preliminary tests, but now I think I should comprehensive test before hunting for alternate solutions. Will be back to post that.

Answer (score 0):

i have done datamigrations from different Schema and it took around 30 minutes for 2 million records with load, transform / merge with existing, save on my dev mashine. so maybe there is still room for improvement

things which could speed up

- work in batches and use `session.clear()` after each to get rid of previously cached data (otherwise flush will get more expensive over time)
- use prefetch paths when loading the object graph
- cache often needed data (XYZType) inmemory and session.attach after each `clear()`
- profile where most time is used
- not sure if it applies to hibernate but NHibernate has reflection optimizer: use the sessionfactories classmetadata instead of reflection to set properties
- enable batching of update statements